# Global named event equivalent in Unix

Tags: winapi, unix, synchronization, ipc

What is the global named event object equivalent in Unix? I need to create a named event-like object in unix so that another process can set it

pseudocode in Win32:

```
HANDLE hEvent=CreateEvent(...,"Global\\CSAPP");
while(1)
{
    WaitForSingleObject(hEvent);
    ...
}
```

In another process:

```
HANDLE hEvent=OpenEvent(...,"Global\\CSAPP");
SetEvent(hEvent);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for a [named semaphore](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html).

```
int initial = 0;
sem_t *sem = sem_open("/global_name", O_CREAT, 0644, initial);

/* Down ("Wait"). */
sem_wait(sem);

/* Up ("Set") . */
sem_post(sem);
```

Comment: @JosephH Tweak the permissions.

Comment: No, a semaphore is not the same thing as an event object, because it isn't binary! You can signal an Event 10 times, then wait on it and manually reset it in one atomic operation (of resetting it). With a semaphore, you would have to call sem_wait 10 times to reset the it back to zero. This is not only inefficient, but the ten calls to sem_wait would not be atomic, either (an operation to increase the semaphore's count could be performed in the middle). The Linux eventfd syscall is about as close as you can get, but it isn't named, so the answer is there is no good way to do this on Unix.