# C++ Synchronization across processes

Tags: c++, process, synchronization

I have an exe written in C++ whose code has an if/else loop. If loop checks for files from a directory and if its empty, it generates the files in that directory. Else loop (if there are files in directory), it reads those files and fills the data structures.

Now multiple instances of this exe are running. One instance has to generate the files into the directory and all other instances should read them. How can I synchronize the instances? I mean when one instance generates the files all other should wait and the generating exe should signal something after all the files are generated, so that other instances start reading them. Do we have any construct in standard C++ to synchronize across the processes?

Comment: The term you need to research is [*Inter-Process Communication* (IPC for short)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication).

Comment: Standard has nothing if the sort. Each OS has its own routines and there are some libraries that wrap these up like boost

Comment: You could use a sentinel file that means the reading processes should only read the directory if it exists. But you should not use directories as databases.

Comment: Better if you could mention in your question on which platform(Linux or Windows ) you want to achieve it.

Comment: Synchronizing with files is a very fragile a solution.  Have a look at [gRPC ](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/quickstart/) (it is a very useful skill to have). First you can use it to send a signal (make a call) to another process. Or you can directly use it to transfer data without files at all. The nice thing is gRPC uses the network stack so later you can use it to run the code on two different computers without change.

Comment: "One instance has to generate the files into the directory and all other instances should read them." Why those operations should be performed simultaneously ? I would rather create all files at first, then assign files to be updated to the processes. If you do not want to manage processes, give them a fixed list of files to be processed as arguments.

Comment: Standard C++ lacks concept of processes. Processes are feature of (multiprocessing) operating systems. You mention "exe" so you want it for Windows? Answers to this question may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31270314/how-do-i-synchronize-two-processes-in-c-windows

Comment: Its platform independent executable. It should run in both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any standard way of doing this. I had the same problem once, and I used system level calls to create a special lock file (`open` in Linux, `CreateFile` in Windows, with the appropriate arguments to create the file if it didn't exist, but use the existing file if it did), and then use the appropriate system call to lock this new file. After that, you can check whether the files you're interested in exist, and create them if not.

Answer (score 0):

If a sentinel file is unsuitable, you can try using a "named event" or semaphore.

**Named Events with Windows**

- call `SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS)`
- Use [CreateEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventw) to try to create a "named event". This means that you need to provide a name in the `lpName` parameter. Check the return value and `GetLastError`.
- If `CreateEvent` succeeds, proceed to update directory. Call [SetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-setevent) after creating the files.
- If named event already exists, use [WaitForSingleObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobject) or [WaitForMultipleObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitformultipleobjects) to wait until the other process has finished.

**Semaphores with POSIX**

- Call [sem_open](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_open.html) with `oflag` set to `O_CREAT | O_EXCL`.
- If sem_open succeeds, proceed to update directory. Call [sem_post](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sem_post.html) on completion.
- If sem_open failed because the semaphore already existed, call sem_wait.

Note that there are [differences between Event and Semaphore behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574619/global-named-event-equivalent-in-unix).

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Events/WaitForSingleObject etc works on Windows. If there is something which can work both in window/linux it will be great. I too know that processes are specific to OS. I was thinking C++17 or C++20 might have added some feature for process synchronization